# Splitting field of a separable polynomial is also the splitting field of an irreducible separable polynomial

Tags: field-theory, extension-field, splitting-field

Let $F$ be a field and let $K$ be the splitting field for the separable polynomial $p(x) \in F[x]$. Prove that $K$ is the splitting field for an irreducible, separable polynomial $q(x)$ in $F[x]$.

**Attempt:**

My idea is that we can use $p(x)$ to find $q(x)$. If $p(x)$ is irreducible, we are done, because we can take $p(x) = q(x)$. If not, then write $p(x) = p_1(x) p_2(x)$. Now I want to argue that if either $p_1(x)$ or $p_2(x)$ is irreducible, then we are done, since any factor of $p(x)$ is still separable; so suppose $p_1(x)$ is irreducible. However, how can I be sure that the splitting field for $p_1(x)$ is $K$ and not something smaller?

Comment: Let $F=\mathbb Q$, and let $p(x)=(x^2+2)(x^2+3)$, but splitting field of $p_1(x)=(x^2+2)$ isn't $K$.

Comment: @DavidCheng So in other words my idea does not work? We need to find $q(x)$ in some other way?

Comment: Yes. To get some idea, you can find $q(x)$ for the example I gave above.

Comment: @DavidCheng Does the idea you have in mind find $q(x)$ explicitly or does your idea just prove that such $q(x)$ exists?

Comment: My idea is constructing an element $\alpha$ such that $F(\alpha)=K$, then $q$ can be the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$. In my above example, $\mathbb Q(\sqrt 2+\sqrt 3)=\mathbb Q(\sqrt 2,\sqrt 3)=$

Comment: @DavidCheng In your example, how can the splitting field for your $p(x)$ be $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3})$? The splitting field has to include some nonreal complex numbers, and all the elements in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3})$ are real.

Comment: opps I meant $p(x)=(x^2-2)(x^2-3)$, but both examples should work the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From David's example, the factors of $p(x)$ are not going to be helpful, because while they cover some of the roots of $p(x)$, they may not cover enough to get to the same splitting field.

Use instead the primitive element theorem. The extension $K / F$ is finite and separable (why?) so by the theorem , $K = F[\alpha]$ for some $\alpha \in K$. Think about  the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $F$.

Comment: The theorem I had in mind to use is that a finite separable extension is simple. From that I would get that $K = F(\alpha)$ for some $\alpha \in K$ and the minimal polynomial for $\alpha$ would be the irreducible separable polynomial I am looking for. But I do not see why it must be a separable extension. While it is true that it is the splitting field for a particular separable polynomial $p(x)$, I don't see why every element of $K$ must be a separable element.

Comment: "I don't see why every element of $K$ must be separable" well, $K$ is the splitting field of some separable polynomial $p$ over $F$. That means that $K$ is generated by the roots of $p$. One can show that element separability is closed under field operations i.e. the sum/difference/product/quotient of separable elements is separable. Since each of the roots of $p$ is separable, $K$ itself becomes separable. Finally, the extension $K : F$ is finite (it has degree at most $(\deg p)!$) so you can use the result.

Comment: Assuming that I show that $K$ is a separable extension, can I then say that $K$ is finite because it's the splitting field of a polynomial and therefore the degree of the extension is at most deg($p(x)$)!, and since it's also separable it is simple, and therefore the minimal polynomial is irreducible (and separable because the extension is separable)?

Comment: @Junglemath Yes, everything you say is fine : but you need to show that $K$ is the splitting field of that minimal polynomial over $F$ to finish the argument. That is quite easy.

Comment: If you liked my answer and the comments, then kindly upvote and accept. Thank you for the consideration.